# catkin_make error

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i am a beginner of learning ROS.

I write a node of image processing with Halcon library.
As far as I know, it should be configured well, in `CMakeList.txt`, to make the node pass the compile.
The following is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(daheng_try_cmdvel)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  tf
)

generate_messages(  DEPENDENCIES  std_msgs )
catkin_package()

include_directories(
${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
/home/zcn/Downloads/daheng-1.3.1305.9271-32/sdk/include
/home/zcn/Downloads/daheng-1.3.1305.9271-32/sdk/genicam/library/CPP/include
/home/zcn/Downloads/halcon-7.0.4-linux-x86/include
/home/zcn/Downloads/halcon-7.0.4-linux-x86/include/cpp
)

link_directories(
/usr/lib/
/home/zcn/Downloads/daheng-1.3.1305.9271-32/sdk/genicam/bin/Linux32_i86/
/home/zcn/Downloads/daheng-1.3.1305.9271-32/sdk/genicam/bin/Linux32_i86/GenApi/Generic/
/home/zcn/Downloads/halcon-7.0.4-linux-x86/lib/i586-linux2.2
)

add_executable(daheng_try_cmdvel_node src/daheng_try_cmdvel_node.cpp)

target_link_libraries(daheng_try_cmdvel_node
${catkin_LIBRARIES}

gxiapi
pthread
dhgentl

GCBase_gcc40_v2_3
GenApi_gcc40_v2_3 
log4cpp_gcc40_v2_3
Log_gcc40_v2_3
MathParser_gcc40_v2_3
Xalan-C_gcc40_v1_10
XalanMessages_gcc40_v1_10
Xerces-C_gcc40_v2_7
XMLLoader_gcc40_v2_3

halconcpp
)
add_dependencies(daheng_try_cmdvel_node daheng_try_cmdvel_generate_messages_cpp)
```

But, when I catkin_make, it shows:

```
CMakeFiles/daheng_try_cmdvel_node.dir/src/daheng_try_cmdvel_node.cpp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
daheng_try_cmdvel_node.cpp:(.text+0x772): undefined reference to `HTuple::HTuple()'
CMakeFiles/daheng_try_cmdvel_node.dir/src/daheng_try_cmdvel_node.cpp.o: In function `HTuple::~HTuple()':
daheng_try_cmdvel_node.cpp:(.text._ZN6HTupleD2Ev[_ZN6HTupleD5Ev]+0xc): undefined reference to `vtable for HTuple'
collect2: ld return 1
make[2]: *** [/home/zcn/catkin_ws/devel/lib/daheng_try_cmdvel/daheng_try_cmdvel_node] error 1
make[1]: *** [daheng_try_cmdvel/CMakeFiles/daheng_try_cmdvel_node.dir/all]  error  2
make: *** [all]  error  2
Invoking "make" failed
```

why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206468/catkin_make-error/) by [whenand](https://answers.ros.org/users/22061/whenand/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This appears to be a generic C++ question, not related to ROS or catkin. It looks like you are using a class called `HTuple` which you have included the header for, but have neglected to link the library which contains the implementation. Your `CMakeLists.txt` has some pretty unorthodox stuff in it.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [whenand](https://answers.ros.org/users/22061/whenand/) on 2015-04-28**:
Thanks William, how to fix this problem? I search in the web, they mentioned something about g++ compiling. here, i use catkin_make.